# PDI slow loading into azure databases

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-storage, pentaho-data-integration, pdi

I have an Azure VM with Pentaho Data Integration installed, i'm trying to build some ETL which loads a dimensional model from the staging area, but when i start a transformation, the load speed of PDI into any azure database is painfully slow.

It is possible to have PDI working on cloud with Azure Databases? There is some configuration step needed to achieve a reasonable loading speed?

PS:

- VM and databases are in the same region
- There is a firewall rule to allow port acess
- Reading speed is working just fine
- PDI 8.1, using table output step

Comment: you could check whether PDI uses batch inserts. If it for some reason doesn't, every insert would be a roundtrip to the Azure database. With the usual delay that comes with such a connection, you would see a pretty poor performance. Selects are quick because they don't process rows individually. https://wiki.pentaho.com/display/EAI/Table+Output

Comment: I have nothing to add to Dirk Trilsbeek's comment. Please add `azure-storage` and `azure-sql-database` to your tags. In facts, I did it for you, and because you only have 5 tags allowed, I removed ETL and Kettle as redundant.

Comment: Are you using the latest JDBC driver for SQL Server? Please update.

Comment: @DirkTrilsbeek, batch inserts are enabled

Comment: are you sure it is actually used? Checking the checkbox in the table output step doesn't mean it is active, it just means PDI will try using batch inserts if possible. The database does have to support batch inserts. You could try catching the inserts through logging to see what's going on. If batch inserts are used, you could try increasing your commit in the output step.

Comment: @AlbertoMorillo, no, i was not, so i updated it to the latest(7.0 now) and i'm still having the same problem

Comment: @DirkTrilsbeek i dug deeper into this batch inserts thing and now i think it is not being used, i found this [issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/mssql-jdbc/issues/331) and i think pdi is not ready to use bulk inserts for Azure Data Warehouse yet

Comment: [another documentation about](https://github.com/Microsoft/mssql-jdbc/wiki/How-to-enable-Bulk-Copy-API-for-batch-insert-operations)

Comment: 7.0? whats that for, pdi? Latest pdi is currently 8.1 and 8.2 is due out in days. (and can be built from source)

Comment: @Codek that stands for [SQL Server JDBC driver](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=57175), i'm using pdi 8.1

Comment: Well, as a workaround, i replaced Azure DW with a **S12 Azure SQL Database**,  and set this parameter: **useBulkCopyForBatchInsert=true** on my JDBC connection, now i'm getting 50k rows/sec, with parallel writes.

Answer (score 1):

I've been experiencing same speed problem but I will tell you my workarounds with this.

**First of all:** Download and install latest jdbc driver that lets you gain connection with azure sql database, in documentation the link is [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=57782)  but the way I do is keep it synced from here in [GitHub](https://github.com/Microsoft/mssql-jdbc) any of this will let you use the latest driver in PDI.

**Second workaround:** for large files what I've found most powerful is using [BCP Utility](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/bcp-utility?view=sql-server-2017) integrated with PowerShell or Linux Batch. Doesn't care if it files are local or in azure blob storage but you might need credentials for this.

**Last but not least:** Use [Azure Data Factory V2](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/data-factory/) to move and load files (if you are like me I try to keep it in PDI until I have to load it, the *http get step* will let you trigger ADF pipeline).

Good luck and let me know if you get it.